# Add/remove classes on element/component during page transitions in layout/default.vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, page-transition

I am looking for a solution to add and remove classes on components/elements outside of the `<nuxt/>` element in `layouts/default.vue` during page transitions in a Nuxt project.

As an example, I would like to animate a `div` in and then out before every page transition. Pseudo code below:

```html
<!-- layouts/default.vue -->

<template>
  <site-curtain :class="{ 'is-active': isTransitioning == true }" /> // I would to apply this class during a page transition
  <nuxt />
</template>
```

Is there an obvious way in Nuxt to listen to the page transitions that I am missing? I have looked at vue-router's `beforeRouteUpdate` navigation guard but not sure if it's suitable?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this (I used this approach in one of my projects and it works fine):

first I defined a mixin as follows:

`mixin/transition.js`:

```js
export default {
  beforeEnter() {
    this.$emit('transition', true);
  },
  afterEnter() {
    this.$emit('transition', false);
  },
}
```

then imported it in every page that I wanted to use the effect:

`pages/about-us.vue`

```js
import transition from '@/mixin/transition';

export default {
  mixins: [transition],
  ...
}
```

then in the layout page I could listen to the `transition` event emited before and after the transition is done and get the payload sent with the event:

```html
<template>
  <site-curtaion :class="{ 'is-active': isTransition }" />
  <nuxt @transition="isTransition = $event" />
</template>
```

and this is the `data` object of the layout component:

```js
data() {
  return {
    isTransition: false,
  };
}
```

here is the resources I used to put together this solution:

[Nuxt transition properties](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-transition#the-pagetransition-property)

[Vue's javascript transition hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just implemented as above but it seems the `@transition` never fires in Nuxt and class is never added? Do I need to register `@transition` as custom event?

Comment: @strnr I'm so sorry! totally forgot to post the full solution, (project was quite for a long time ago and didn't check it out completely before posting my answer), anyway I updated the answer with the full solution, I hope it helps